# Get 100 shades of blue color in Textbox

Tags: c#, css, winforms

I'm trying to get different blue color shades using C# code. I am managing to get different colors but not in shades of blue.

How can I fix this code :-

```
public MainWindow()
{
    InitializeComponent();

    double decValue = 255;

    var converter = new System.Windows.Media.BrushConverter();
    for (int i = 0; i < 100; i++)
    {

        string hexValue = decValue.ToString();
        var brush = (System.Windows.Media.Brush)converter.ConvertFromString("#" + hexValue.ToString());

        TextBox txt = new TextBox();
        txt.Width = 30;
        txt.Width = 90;

        txt.Background = brush;
        decValue = decValue - 1;
        lst.Items.Add(txt);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I suggest the following, more direct approach - without strings, hex codes and converters:

```
for (int i = 0; i < 100; i++)
{
  byte r = 0;
  byte g = 0;
  byte b = (byte)(255 - i);

  var color = System.Windows.Media.Color.FromRgb(r, g, b);
  var brush = new System.Windows.Media.SolidColorBrush(color);
  // Use brush here...
}
```

Answer (score 3):

`#255` is the equivalent of `#225555`. You need to convert your decimal value into hexidecimal instead of just converting it to a string (255 = FF) and add `"0000"` to the start of the string to make it a valid color code.

To convert decimal to hexidecimal you use the overloaded `toString` function as follows:

```
string hexValue = decValue.ToString("X");
```

The "X" format string means Hexidecimal so `255.ToString("X")` will return the hexadecimal string "FF". For more information see [msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dwhawy9k.aspx](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dwhawy9k.aspx)

Then for your brush use the following:

```
var brush = (System.Windows.Media.Brush)converter.ConvertFromString("#0000" + hexValue);
```